# Prove a transformation involving evaluating a polynomial is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Hy i have a small problem. I need to prove that a transformation $$\mathbb{R}_{3}[ x ] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{3}$$ $$\phi (p):= [p(-1), p(0), p(1)]^T$$  is linear. 
The $$\mathbb{R}_{3}[ x ]$$ vector space is a degree of max 3.
Then i need to find the basis of the transformation kernel and basis of the image.

How would i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea on how to prove that the transformation is linear ?

Comment: Yes is has to maintain addition T(A+B) = T(A) + T(B) and it has to map T(alpha * A), plus it needs to map $$0$$ to $$0$$ which i don't think it does. But how to prove that ?

Comment: Yes but not only. With your notations, you need to prove that :

$$\forall (p,q) \in \mathbb{R}_{3}[X], \, \phi(p+q) = \phi(p)+\phi(q) \tag{1}$$

**and**

$$ \forall p \in \mathbb{R}_{3}[X], \, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \, \phi(\lambda p) = \lambda \phi(p) \tag{2}$$

Comment: Yes, but I don't seem to understand what to put inside of p and q, wouldn't that be just $$[-1,0,1]^T$$ ?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are *any* polynomials in $\mathbb{R}_{3}[X]$. Looking at the first component of $\phi(p+q)$, you will have :

$$ (p+q)(-1) $$

which is : the polynomial $(p+q)$ evaluated at $-1$. You can easily see that it is the same as : $p(-1)+q(-1)$.

Comment: Ok but wouldn't that mean that the 0 vector would never be mapped ?

Comment: Here, you have : $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: So i can put anything inside p, even if the transformation explicitly says it is $$[p(-1), p(0), p(1)]^T$$ ?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti : I do not understand. What relation should we prove then ?

Comment: @jibounet You defined the right set of rules. I just don't know how to formalize them in respect to the translation given.

Comment: @jibounet, sorry, I misread. Please have my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very important fact, which is called the *universal property of the polynomial ring*. This is what you need here.

This states (in a simplified form) that if $K$ is a field, $A$ is a commutative ring containing $K$ as a subring, and $\alpha \in A$, then there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi: K[x] \to A$ of rings (actually, of $K$-algebras) such that
$$
\varphi(k) = k, \ \text{for $k \in K$},
\quad\text{and}\quad
\varphi(x) = \alpha.
$$
The unique $\varphi$ is nothing else that *evaluation at $\alpha$*, that is, the map that takes a polynomial $p(x)$ to its value $p(\alpha)$.